# Automating click to image-mapped actions/links using Node/Nightwatch

Tags: node.js, automated-tests, nightwatch.js

How does one use NightwatchJs to automate clicking a specific part of an image? My naive approach is to select the coords attribute that matches the specific area of the image I'd like to trigger; but it doesn't work.

```
<img src="..." usemap="#example">
<map name="example" id="example">
    <area shape="rect" coords="336,10,401,32" href="...">
    <area shape="rect" coords="25,171,97,198" href="...">
    ...
</map>
```

Anyone encounter this issue or know of a work around? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would play with the **position** of `area` elements inside the `map` element using CSS selectors like `:first-child` or `:first-of-type`. Here is a minimal working example:

**PNG** (*map.png*)

[image: Image map]

**HTML/JS** (*index.html*)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Nightwatch</title>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="map.png" usemap="#map">
  <map name="map">
    <area shape="circle" coords="51,51,29">
  </map>
  <script>
    // When the red area is clicked, we should display an alert.
    var area = document.querySelector('area');
    area.addEventListener('click', function () {
      alert('OK');
    }, false);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Nightwatch** (*script.js*)

```
module.exports = {
  'Clickable image map': function (browser) {
    browser
      .url('http://localhost:8000/index.html')
      .waitForElementPresent('map', 1000)
      .click('map > area:first-child');
      // ...
  },
};
```

**Command**

If your environment is properly set up, you can run the script with `nightwatch -t tests/script.js`. You will see the alert, meaning that the red area has been clicked by Nightwatch.

Comment: Thanks, your answer worked for chrome. For some reason it didn't work on firefox. Do you have any suggestion? I ran querySelector on firefox to select it on the same way as I did with chrome, and it selects it, but when I ran it on nightwatch it doesn't click the link.